# If program is not running, re-launch it by checking his pid

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Can one of you tell me if my bash script seems good. My goal is that this script looks in bash.pid (file that contains the pid number) then if the pid is running, the script goes exit 0 and if not, it re-runs the program my executing ./run

the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Printing the directory
pwd > dir.dir
dir=$(cat dir.dir)
# Identifying the directory
pid=\$(cat $dir/bash.pid
# looking if pid is running - if it is running just exit
if \$(kill -CHLD \$pid >/dev/null 2>&1)
then
exit 0
fi
fi
# if not running then re-launch the program
cd $dir
./run &>/dev/null" > upd
chmod u+x upd
./upd
```

Thanks.

Comment: For a reason when pasting the code, some of my comments went at the wrong lines, but since it's only comments, the script remains ok

Comment: see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331824/bash-script-to-re-launch-program-in-case-of-failure-error

Comment: Thanks but it won't do what i need too since the number inside of bash.pid can change

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if the application "run" or "udp" is the one which you want to run. Let's suppose it is "run".

At the end of your script, the pid of run should be write to the bash.pid for the script next checking.

After we restart "run", we should double confirm if it started.

Usually we use run.pid to keep the pid of run.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Printing the directory
pwd > dir.dir
dir=$(cat dir.dir)
# Identifying the directory
pid=$(cat $dir/bash.pid)
# looking if pid is running - if it is running just exit
if $(kill -CHLD $pid >/dev/null 2>&1)
then
    echo  "run has been started\n"
    exit 0
fi
# if not running then re-launch the program
cd $dir
chmod u+x run
./run & 
pgrep run > bash.pid
pid=$(cat $dir/bash.pid)
if $(kill -CHLD $pid >/dev/null 2>&1)
    echo "failed to start run \n"
then
    echo  "run has been started\n"
fi
```